# No Font-Awesome icons of theme

Tags: less, font-awesome, impresspages

Can anybody tell me how to set up Font Awesome to work with a theme?

I have put this in my template file:

```
    <div id="social-media-bar" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <i class="fa fa-xing-square fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But there are no icons loaded. They aren't loaded in admin mode either but the IP menus have their FA icons as they should.

What am I doing wrong? Are some LESS entries necessary in my theme?

Comment: have you included there script or css file

Comment: And please show us the declarations. The Font name is `Fontawesome` and not `Font-Awesome`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!

I haven't included it in my less files yet because I thought that it's included by default via the ipContent.less. 
Looks like I was wrong ;-) 

Am I right that I should include it via my theme.less? 
How exactly?

I would like to avoid to load thing twice ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Bootstraps CDN in the head now:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it - I just have added this line to theme.less:

```
@import "/Ip/Internal/Core/assets/admin/font-awesome/font-awesome.less";
```

Comment: Hm, strange - it does not seem to work. 
What is the best-practice strategy to implement Font Awesome in my theme?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add css in Impresspages is by using [ipAddCSS](https://www.impresspages.org/docs/ipaddcss) in you theme header before `ipHead()`. Thats the same way you can add css to plugins.

For example:

```
<head>
    <?php ipAddCss('Theme/AHS/assets/ahs.css'); ?>
    <?php echo ipHead(); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Tim - it may be helpful to post a proof-of-concept solution.